# Galleria - imagePosition problem in IE8 (galleria.aino.se)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, galleria

I have created a website for a makeup artist, and I am using [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/%20link)  to the portfolio. I have a problem with the imagePosition property in IE8. Even if i use **imagePosition: 'center'**, is the image positioned to the left in IE8. (The other browsers centers the image)

Here is the code:

```
function initGalleria(){
      $('#galleria').galleria({
        debug:true,
        imageCrop:'height',
        imagePan:true,
        imagePanSmoothness:10,
        imagePosition:'center',
        transition:'fade',
        transitionSpeed:500,
        idleTime:1000,
        queue:false,
        extend: function() {
            this.attachKeyboard({
                left: this.prev, // applies the native prev() function
                right: this.next
            });
            this.addIdleState(this.get('thumbnails-container'), {
                opacity: 0
            });
            this.addIdleState(this.get('info-link'), {
                opacity: 0
            });
        }
    });
}
```

... and a [link to the website](http://www.christaajris.se)  I'm working on.

Do you have any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: your .scrollable .items has a style of width: 20000em;

Answer (score 0):

@swenedo I don't know what wrong with your code. It's absolute right. I tested it on Chrome 10, FF 4, IE 8 and it got nothing wrong. I posted a screen picture when I open your website on IE8, it's in center.
[image]

Comment: your screenshot isn't from the Portfolio. The problem is the galleria I am using in the Portfolio. But thanks for your test :)